# File differences

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-10, notepad

I have two notepad files.
One created in Windows 7 and another in Windows 10.
But both have different size (even same content) and somehow different 'format' that make my other program read both differently.
How do I check the differences? How can I make notepad that same regardless the Windows version?

Both file just have the word DATA

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Encoding. 
Windows 7 is saving as ANSI, while 10 is saving as Unicode (UCS-2 LE BOM), probably.
May help you: [Changing the Default Ansi to UTF-8](https://superuser.com/questions/557023/changing-the-default-ansi-to-utf-8-in-notepad)

[image: Box to define encoding (pt-br however)]

Comment: Thanks. Its helps at least for me to start Googling more. Didn't expect as simple as Notepad I waste hours of headache.